A possible generalization of Brauer's theorem about the prime factors of the period and index of a central simple algebra
Let $K$ be an arbitrary field, and let $K^s$ be a fixed separable closure of $K$.
Let $F/K$ a be a finite Galois extension in $K^s$.
Let $n>0$ be a natural number.
Let $A$ be a central simple algebra over $F$ such that $A^{\otimes n}$ is split.
By Brauer's theorem, $A$ can be split
by a finite separable extension $L/F$ of degree dividing $n^r$ for some $r\ge 0$;
see Theorem 2.8.7 in the book by Philippe Gille and Tamás Szamuely "Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology", 2nd edition, Cambridge 2017.

Conjecture.
There exists a finite separable extension $C/K$ in $K^s$
of degree dividing $n^{r}$ for some $r\ge 0$
such that the extension $L=CF$ of $F$ splits $A$.

I can prove this conjecture in the case when $K$ is a local or global field.

Question. Is this conjecture true over an arbitrary field (or over any field of characteristic 0)?

Please add suitable tags!
